# How to align vertically UISearchBar and right bar button items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am working on iOS application. It has search bar and right bar button items (a couple of buttons).

The stuff is initialized as follows:

```
UISearchController *searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
UISearchBar *searchBar = searchController.searchBar;
[searchBar sizeToFit];
searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";

UIButton *routeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[routeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"go_route"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
routeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0., 0., 30., 30.);

UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(0., 0., 30., 30.);

UIBarButtonItem *routeButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:routeButton];
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:cancelButton];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[cancelButtonItem, routeButtonItem];
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
```

Functionally, it works as expected, but looks a bit strange: buttons are drawn a bit upper than the search bar:

[image]

I would like to have the buttons a bit lower to be aligned vertically with the search bar. How do I achieve it?

P.S.
It seems that if I change y-coordinate in `cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(0., y, 30., 30.);` -- it makes no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your codes in viewDidAppear as follows,

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Enter your code

}
```

You will get the navigation items centred, And If still the frame is not updated try,

Updating its "y" position in viewDidAppear, else try as below to set frame exactly adjacent to search bar,

```
routeButton.center = CGPointMake(routeButton.center.x, searchBar.center.y);
```